# Proper way of handling DB calls in a TCP Application

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm currently in the progress of working on a telephone application, and for easy portability I'm making use of Unity3D. The application's design looks nice and crisp and scales well into all of my target resolutions, but the networking is giving me an issue.

I'm using Java for the server backend, and I'm using JDBC to mananage database connections. The problem is that this application is sure to have a few thousand users at minimum (Based on my current following, blogs, and marketing techniques) and I would like to make sure that I'm doing this correctly to avoid any lockups from SQL being used at the same time.

This application pulls everything that is needed from the database. For security and glitch prevention reasons if the database cannot be connected the server lets the client(application) know that there was an error.

**Here's what I'm worried about:**  When a user logs in a few things are done almost instantly. The database is checked for their login credentials, if it's successful the client then loads the next stage of the application then sends a packet to the server. The server then grabs more information from the server (This is done through a total of three queries in the shortest form I can possibly come up with.) However; What happens if a 2-300 people are logging in, 3-400 are spending tokens (Requires db calls) and 2-300 are requesting database data elsewhere. That's around 1,000 requested database calls coming in.

**I don't want the application to seem really laggy.**

Here's how I'm currently handling it after a little research, but it doesn't feel necessarily right. Looking for advice and corrections. (decodeTCP is called when a packet with the header id of X is received.)

```
public void decodeTcp(Session session) throws IOException {
    try {
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable<Object>() {
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return Database.getSingleton().fetch((User)session.getAttachment());
            }
        }, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        int results = (int) scheduledFuture.get();scheduledFuture.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Where `Database#fetch(Object)` returns an int.